# pyTorch autoencoder for unsupervised classification: loss not changing

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning, softmax

I'm new to pyTorch.  I want to use the autoencoder concept to get an unsupervised classification.  It seems like you should be able to use the minimum dimension from the autoencoder as input to a softmax fx. I used a "dummy" copy of the data to implement the loss fx. However, I can't get the loss to change and I don't understand why.

```
x = pd.read_csv(<file.csv>)
xray=x.to_numpy()
tx = torch.from_numpy(xray)
txr = tx.float()
txr.requires_grad=True
dmmy=torch.nn.Linear(22,6)(txr)
class AE(nn.Module):
    `def __init__(self):`
        `torch.autograd
        self.L1=nn.Linear(in_features=22, out_features=20)
        self.E1=nn.ELU(alpha=9)                          
        ...
        ...
        self.L7=nn.Linear(in_features=8, out_features=6)
        self.E7=nn.ELU(alpha=9)`
    `def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor, retain_graph=True):`
         `torch.autograd
          L1 = self.L1(x)
          E1 = self.E1(L1)
          ...
          ... 
          L7 = self.L7(E6)
          E7 = self.E7(L7)
          return E7`
Lossfx = torch.nn.MSELoss()
opt=torch.optim.SGD(params=m.parameters(), lr=0.01)
epochs=2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    `m.train()
    pred=m(txr)
    loss=Lossfx(dmmy,pred)
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    print(f'loss: {loss}')
    print(f'pred: {pred[0]}')
    opt.zero_grad()
    opt.step()`
print('Done')
**## Softmax after training/testing e.g. ypred=nn.Softmax(dim=1)(pred)**
## Result
Loss: 38.851
pred[0]: [ 4.6630, -8.9925, -8.9977,  6.2631,  2.2962,  2.2374]
dmmy[0]: [-0.1594, -0.2595, -0.2731,  0.2965, -0.0969,  0.5345]

Loss: 38.851
pred[0]: same
dmmy[0]: same
```

Comment: For evaluating your code, print Loss and Predictions at each training examples. Moreover, apply normalization to each datapoint. 
Regarding your Activation function, In your AE module, you are using the ELU activation function with a high alpha value (9). This might cause the activations to saturate and hinder the learning process. Try using a smaller alpha value or experiment with other activation functions such as ReLU or sigmoid to see if it improves the model's performance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question so that it shows your problem if someone were to copy/paste it into their own interpreter? It will make it much easier to pinpoint the problem. Also one problem I'm seeing is that you're not zeroing your gradient with opt.zero_grad() after stepping, this will make it so that the gradient accumulates (as in arithmetic addition) on the leaves, which is great for getting the average of multiple batches or training RNNs, but not great for users new to the PyTorch framework. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example